# Sniffing The URL and parameters in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

When I sniffing using the python with scapt, The Password is encrypted in hash but in Ettercap it's normal?

See this picture:

[image: Here...]

Inside the red box  you see the username, password even the INFO.Aside from it, The Password doesn't encrypted with hashes.

But when I'm using the python, The Password is encrypted with hash?

[image: Here...]

Why is it happen and how can I fix that?
By the way this is the code.

```
from scapy.all import *
import re

def get_credentials(source):
    username = None
    password = None
    userfields = ['username', 'user', 'name', 'login', 'nickname', 'userfield', 'login-name', 'log',
    "email", "login-id", 'user-name', 'userID', 'userid', 'user-id', 'login_name', 'login-name', 'login-user', 'login_user', 'account', 'acc-name',
    "account-user", "account-name"]
    passfields = ['passwords', 'pword', 'pwd', 'user-passwords', 'pass', '_password', 'password', 'password', 'pwords', 'login-passwords', 'login-pword', 'login-pwords', 'user-password', 'user-paswd']

    for login in userfields:
        user = re.search('(%s=[^&]+)' % login, source, re.IGNORECASE)
        if user:
            username = user.group()

    for p in passfields:
        passwd = re.search('(%s=[^&]+)' % p, source, re.IGNORECASE)
        if passwd:
            password = passwd.group()

    if username and password != None:
        return username, password

def ctp(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Ether) and pkt.haslayer(Raw) and not pkt.haslayer(IP) and not pkt.haslayer(IPv6):
        pass

    if pkt.haslayer(TCP) and pkt.haslayer(Raw) and pkt.haslayer(IP):
        mains = str(bytes(pkt[TCP].payload))
        source = str(pkt[TCP].payload)
        creds = get_credentials(source)
        if creds != None:
            print(creds)
    else:
        pass

print('SNIFFING')
sniff(iface="lo", prn=ctp, store=0) # lo is my Local Loopback interface
```

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Now let's see if we can clarify it. What are you trying to do, and what's not working? I think maybe you're trying to see `password` sent on the network but in reality you're seeing a hashed version? The [ask] page has some great tips for asking technical questions effectively. The easier your question is to understand, the easier it is to answer.

Comment: Question si updated? Is it ok now?

Comment: What sort of encoding is being used in the post? Might be best to use the HTTP-layer

Comment: HTTP Layer? what do you mean?